# Site Stats widget that links to "more info" on stack exchange

Tags: bug, site-stats

I don't know how it's supposed to work, but I think it doesn't work at all right now.

Try clicking the lowest link in this widget:

[image]

I just get the list of all sites and on top of the page despite the anchor link in the url.